# Change how ConEmu matches URIs to convert to clickable links when holding modifier key

Tags: conemu

Upon holding `LCtrl` to make URIs clickable and hovering a link in ConEmu, the protocol fragment does not include `-` in the match by default.

In the example string
`example-protocol://someurl` only `protocol://someurl` becomes part of the link.

How can I adjust this behavior to include dashes in the match?

Edit: Thank you very much Maximus :)

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/blog/2016/12/03/Build-161203.html

Comment: @Maximus My god... that was fast. Will this work on custom protocols (created manually in registry) like ssh:// ?

Comment: It already worked with all protocols that did not include any dashes.